# Обратиться к макроопределениям GET_X_LPARAM и GET_Y_LPARAM

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

В виду необходимости, нет смысла передавать в метод оба параметра, а так же выделять динамическую память под `POINTS` во время обработки сообщения `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, и т.д. Приходится использовать `MAKEPOINTS(lparam)`, что способствует созданию объекта который на самом деле и не нужен, при этом макроопределения `GET_X_LPARAM` и `GET_Y_LPARAM` не работают. Но на сайте `MSDN` есть информация что если работать именно с данными макроопределениями, можно получить неверные данные если у пользователя несколько мониторов. Как обойтись без данных макроопределений, когда подключать заголовок `windowsx.h` не имеет смысла ради 2х макроопределений.

Comment: А что значит "макроопределения GET_X_LPARAM и GET_Y_LPARAM не работают"? Как Вы пытались их заставить работать? Добавьте в вопрос кусок кода, чтобы было понятно, о чем идет речь.

Comment: @mega: Работал как `HIWORD` и `LOWORD`, `int x = HIWORD(lparam), y = LOWORD(lparam);` Всегда возвращает `0`

Comment: Ок, тогда давайте по порядку: `int x = (short)HIWORD(lparam), y = (short)LOWORD(lparam);`. Проблема осталась?

Comment: @mega: Огромное спасибо! Проблема исчезла.

Comment: Тогда почитайте статьи на тему "расширения знака". Вот, например: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension

Comment: @mega написать ответом не желаете?

Comment: Спасибо, @alexolut, но у меня на такие ответы красноречие ломается ). Пишите, я не против.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Макроопределения `GET_X_LPARAM` и `GET_Y_LPARAM`, несомненно, работают и возвращают корректные значения независимо от количества мониторов. Если вы нашли где-то в документации указания, что это не так, возможно это ошибка. Они определены в заголовочном файле так:

```
#define GET_X_LPARAM(lp) ((int)(short)LOWORD(lp))
#define GET_Y_LPARAM(lp) ((int)(short)HIWORD(lp))
```

Как видно, тип возвращаемого значения - int (знаковый), поэтому отрицательные координаты будут корректно обрабатываются.

> Как обойтись без данных макроопределений, когда подключать заголовок
>   windowsx.h не имеет смысла ради 2х макроопределений.

Если вам нужны только какие-то отдельные определения из заголовочного файла, их можно просто скопировать к себе в код. Эффект будет тот же.